# Ryanair: Wearable luggage, where's the limit?

Tags: luggage, clothing, hand-luggage, ryanair

Say, I wear pants and a jacket/vest with [PALS webbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pouch_Attachment_Ladder_System), and I attach large sized [pouches](http://store.kifaru.net/pockets-c17.aspx), then where's the limit, i.e. when would Ryanair qualify my clothing as a carry-on bag? Any experience?

Comment: You are best to reckon on Ryan Air behaving as unreasonably as possible in as many situations as possible on all possible occasions, or more. If you happen upon them on an uncharacteristically good day or they fail to notice the opportunity to make maximum $ from you then count it as a bonus. They didn't get where they are today by being reasonable, accommodating or fair - why should you expect them to start with you?

Comment: Or you could simply respect the "contract" you agreed to when you bought the ticket and you won't spend an euro more than their normal cheap price. The fact that other companies usually close an eye (or both) doesn't mean Ryanair is unfair.

Comment: @shard My question is what the contract does allow, because as far as I can tell, this is a gray area. Surely it is OK to put things into the pockets in your pants, or to wear two T-shirts on top of each other, but where's the limit?

Comment: @feklee, there is a missunderstanding: I was replying to the comment of Russel McMahon who stated that Ryanair is usually unfair and unreasonable in any possible situation just because it doesn't close an eye when a person wants to bring on board a (let's say) 15 kg bag. 
For what concerns your question, I agree there is a gray area. In my opinion you should check if these pouches on a pals webbing could be "legally" classified as a bag. I would say so but I'm not a lawyer, so it is just guessing.

Comment: The heaviest item I travel with is the hiking boots. So I wear them. Then I take them off once I am seated. For a really long flight I might take felt slippers in my carry-on bag. I have heard of people doing this with motorcycle leathers plus helmet ( ! ). I don't know if Ryanair would allow this, but I have seen people on Ryanair wearing cycle helmets to go through the gate.

Answer (score 6):

Pouches on a PALS webbing would be an overkill and could qualify as a carry on bag, as it is indeed a bag. Some inventor made this (http://consumerist.com/2012/10/30/avoid-baggage-fees-with-wearable-luggage-if-you-dont-mind-looking-completely-ridiculous/) and people wear this specifically flying Ryanair. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

I can tell you I have done this many times and have carried over 15kg in my coat that has 7 big pockets. I know this because as I was waiting in the queue in Poznan, there was a free scales (unlike UK airports) and I had an idea to see just exactly how much I had in there. The airline did not bat an eyelid.