# Can I really "wear" my luggage?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, clothing, fees-and-charges

There are some jackets with an absurd number of pockets, so that you can put everything that you're bringing on your trip in them (as depicted on [Gadget Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iMUDfXjXc8)). Of course, capacity is comparatively limited, and it would be uncomfortable, but this would probably only be used for short trips on cheap airlines anyways (or "for the lols").

Do these actually work on airlines designed to fleece you with carry-on fees, like RyanAir, Spirit, etc.? Or will they just laugh it off and make you pay the fee?

Comment: I've done it a couple of time, usually wearing a big coat, putting lonely planets in the insides pockets, etc. 

I guess you can do it as long as it's not too obvious, but it definitely works if hand luggage is too heavy or too big for example. (Which is quite stupid at the end, since it all goes in the plane)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of an older question, I just can not find it right now.

Comment: "lonely planets", @Pierpowl?

Comment: @Willeke - seems related to https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16051/1689 at least

Comment: @warren that is the one I was thinking about. Less a copy but still very much related. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: @Willeke - oddly enough ... it's now showing on the right sidebar not only in "linked" but "Related" :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Anything on your person does not count as luggage allowance. Earlier this year I had to fly on some airlines where carry-on had a very low weight limit and on some flights which did not allow a personal item in addition to a carry-on, so I designed a vest and had it custom made for exactly this purpose. What inspired me was [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZkz2QhZpCQ) about another photographer needing to go through check-in with a good amount of gear.

In reality, carry-on are almost never weighed, so I just went in as normal. When I did get weighed, that was only two times (in my whole life even!), I simply moved extra contents from my carry-on and the personal item into my vest. Right at the check-in counter and they said nothing. In one case I emptied my entire personal item, plus stuff from the carry-on and put one into the other since I there was no allowance for a personal item.

Both times I did that at check-in and there were no issues. The vest was designed to handle 12kg with pockets large enough to accommodate a laptop, two professional cameras and four lenses, plus lots of additional items, papers, books, etc. When worn, this gets quite uncomfortable which is why I went each time wearing it but mostly empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down to [point 4 of this page on moneysavingexpert.com](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/travel/beat-budget-airline-charges) then you can see how the journalist Martin Lewis wore his luggage while flying.

It looks like this is still allowed.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.