# Is there a jacket that can store my laptop and various heavy stuff? I'm trying to lower the weight of my bag

Tags: air-travel

Is there a jacket that can store my laptop and various heavy stuff? I'm trying to lower the weight of my bag

I'm trying to switch to carry-on only

Comment: Related: [Can I really "wear" my luggage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100355/can-i-really-wear-my-luggage)

Comment: How long are you traveling for, and in what parts of the world (carry on space varies tremendously). Here in the US, I can go a week using a roller bag (in the bin above) and a small backpack (with laptop/headphones/jacket) below the seat in front of me.

Comment: This is far easy with a little laptop, like a chromebook, but in general it's easier to stuff more smaller items in pockets and make the laptop one of the few things in a bag

Comment: @JonCuster Once you can go more than a few days, then you you can go any length of time with a carry on - washing your clothes away from home is a thing nowadays :D

Comment: @PeterM - true, I'm talking a week of clean clothes in a carryon bag. I'm not wearing suits and plan on wearing the pants a few times, but still...

Comment: @JonCuster I was once visited by some friends on a round the world trip.  When I saw their hand luggage, I asked about the rest of their luggage.  The told me that they didn't have any, and were only traveling with hand luggage.   So from that anecdote, it's possible to travel for extended periods if you are organized.

Comment: Indeed, our last long trip we went with small carry-on bags to Europe. Sure, it took a lazy afternoon or two sitting outside in the sun drinking beer and eating tapas while the laundromat did its thing but it was well worth not dragging big bags around.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps unsurprisingly this is a thing.. some of this will depend on the dimensions of the individual items you need to carry and your clothing size but the range from [SCOTTeVEST](https://www.scottevest.com/best-travel-clothing.shtml) seems to be the sort of thing you're after. IIRC they used to do one that you could actually fit a "full size" laptop in but a quick skim through the site suggest that they might not any more.

I can't testify how good these are - or how comfortable they are when loaded with all the stuff they purport to be able to carry at once, since I've not actually tried one.